# Lookup Full Address For Casascius Coins

Tags: address, physical-coins

Can anyone tell me how I would check the public address on my old Casascius Bitcoins? I have 3 total cons but I am unable to find where or how to check the public addresses on the coins for they only have 8 characters. I have listed all 3 of the pubic addresses below if anyone can help. Thank you in advance.

1) **134xRg9x**
2) **1359wf1p**
3) **1348FHtv**

Thank YOU!

Answer (score 5):

Here is the [full list](http://www.casascius.com/fulllist.txt) of casascius coins.

According to that your addresses are:

1. [134xRg9xsjvmyGxA2ndDbfEw3keqizwzWG](https://blockchain.info/address/134xRg9xsjvmyGxA2ndDbfEw3keqizwzWG)
2. [1359wf1p4wvw7SLa8Fktsg6eJMkbUaXp5y](https://blockchain.info/address/1359wf1p4wvw7SLa8Fktsg6eJMkbUaXp5y)
3. [1348FHtvGk6Cwv9PkFw52BKSQnm1Ujf9zb](https://blockchain.info/address/1348FHtvGk6Cwv9PkFw52BKSQnm1Ujf9zb)